# Using LocalStorage within JS

Tags: javascript, qt, local-storage, qml

So in my app I want to store some data in Sqlite DB. The code is:

**common.js**

```js
.import QtQuick.LocalStorage 2.0 as Sql

function getDatabase() {
    return Sql.LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync("TestDB", "1.0", "Description", 100000);
}
```

**main.qml**

```js
import "common.js" as Common
Item {
    Component.onCompleted: 
        var db = Common.getDatabase();
}
```

But when I run the code I get some strange error: `qrc:/common.js:5: TypeError: Property 'openDatabaseSync' of object [object Object] is not a function`

It looks that this issue works in Maemo ([link](http://kunalmaemo.blogspot.ru/2013/03/using-localstorage-api-from-javascipt.html)). So what I do wrong? Btw, all the files (qml and js) are in resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution. I just replaced

```
import "common.js" as Common
```

with

```
import "qrc:/common.js" as Common
```

But I have no idea why that happens